# Magento 2: Get total weight of cart products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart, product-attribute

I need to get the total weight of products which are added to cart in magento2.

How can We achieve this?

Comment: have you tried to do like `$product->getWeight()` this ?

Comment: $product->getWeight() is used for particular product. but i want weight of all product available in cart.

Comment: For magento 1.9.2.3 how can i use, i mean total weight of cart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution:

We get total weight of products of cart in Magento 2 by `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` class

**With objectManager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

$weight = 0;
foreach($items as $item) {
    $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;        
}

echo $weight;
```

**With Factory Method**

```
protected $_cart;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cartModel,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_cart = $cartModel;
    ...
}

public function getTotalWeight()
{
    $items = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

    $weight = 0;
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;        
    }

    return $weight;
}
```

Comment: Which files would I put this code in?

Comment: How can i find customer add-to-cart overall weight mage 1.9 @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/221525/57334

Comment: Where to put this code ?  @samreg

Comment: it shouldn't be made by custom totals?

Comment: @WojciechKa Can you explain in details ?