# Magento 2 how to get total products weight in order summary

Tags: magento2, frontend

How can i get total products weight in order summary tab where Subtotal and Shipping will be displayed as my req is should display total products weight in cart.

[image]

Comment: can you add screen shot in question where you want exactly ?

Comment: Please check above screenshot..

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/160257/68208

Comment: I have tried that but as i dont got it.. as i had .html file to get value of cart subtotal and shipping..in order summary..

Comment: any update on this?